# How to allow many responses for if statement and replies?

Tags: python

I am making a sort of Siri program. But I'm not sure how to allow various responses, and various replies at random.

Does it involve dictionaries or a simpler alternative, or a random function?

```
if greeting == "Hello", "Hi", "Hey":
    print("Hello", "Hi", "Hey")
else:
    print("I'm not sure what you said there")
```

Comment: What? I don't want it to loop. I want the program to allow the user to write "Hello", "Hi" or "Hey" and receive a response at random from the words "Hello", "Hi" and "Hey".

Comment: My Apologizes. My browser was slow and I was still commenting on another page when it took me here. Thus, my accidental comment post.

Comment: All good brother 

Comment: Thanks man. Just to note though. If you want your 'siri' to keep printing out content, you probably are gonna be using a while-loop.

Comment: what's wrong with `if greeting.lower() in ("hello", "hi", "hey"):` ?

Comment: Yeh, I was just thinking a while-loop signing mandatory. @Mr.Python

Comment: Is if greeting.lower allow the same response for hello and Hello with no case-sensitive error? @Skaperen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick a random response you can use `random.choice`, which selects a random element from a list:

```
import random

if greeting in ["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"]:
    response = random.choice(["Hello", "Hi", "Hey"])
    print(response)
else:
    print("I'm not sure what you said there")
```

Comment: Thank you. May I just ask if it is compulsary to add import random if I want a random selection?

Comment: @MLCLOUD Yes you have to `import random` to use the built in `random` function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about allowing multiple inputs from the user, that would go something like this:

```
if greeting in ["hello", "hi", "hey"]:
    # do stuff
```

If you also want to provide a random response back to the user, you could do something like this:

```
if greeting in ["hello", "hi", "hey"]:
    response = random.choice(["hello", "hi", "hey"])
```